# Input type radio for creating object in many-to-many relationship mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 models: Component, Category (categories of the components) and Sistem.
I want to create a Sistem using already existing components. In the create view I want to use radio input to select the Component, but it seems like the selected one doesn't go where it should.

I have two models that have a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Sistem
    {
        public Sistem()
        {
            this.Components = new HashSet<Component>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }                         
        public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }   
    }

public class Component
    {
        public Component()
        {
            this.Sistems = new HashSet<Sistem>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name {get; set; }
        public ICollection<Sistem> Sistems { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Sistem sistem = new Sistem();
            var categories = from cat in db.Categories select cat;
            ViewBag.Categories = categories;
            sistem.Components = CreateAllComponents();
            return View(sistem);
        }

        public ActionResult Create(Sistem sistem)
        {

            var categories = from cat in db.Categories select cat;
            ViewBag.Categories = categories;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Sisteme.Add(sistem);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            else
                {
                    return View(sistem);
                }
        }
        [NonAction]
        public ICollection<Component> CreateAllComponents()
        {
            Component empty = new Component();
            var listOfComponents = new List<Component>();
            var categories = from cat in db.Categories
                             select cat;
            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                listOfComponents.Add(empty);
            }
            return listOfComponents;
        }
```

Now I want to choose one Component from each Category and add it to the Sistem collection of Categories.
This is in the View for Create:

```
foreach (var cat in @ViewBag.Categories)
{
    int idx = 0;
    <div class="radio-toolbar">
        @foreach (var comp in cat.Components)
        {

                **<input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.Components.ToList()[idx]" id="@comp.Name"  name="@cat.Name" value="@comp"/>
                <label for="@comp.Name" asp-for="@Model.ComponenteSistem.ToList()[idx]"> @comp.Name</label>**
        }
    </div>
    idx = idx + 1;
}
```

It should link every component I choosed with the sistem that I'm currently creating but the relationship table ramains empty:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO9js.png)

I think the problem is this part from the label/input : asp-for="@Model.Components.ToList()[idx] but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. It is a bit unclear what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a little more clear. After I create a Sistem, it should have a collection of components, which I chose from that for in the Create View.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you cannot bind a whole model to radio button( `value="@comp"`).Here is a working demo for binding Component Id and Name to Sistem：
Category Model：

```
public class Category {
        public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
    }
```

View(change checked radio button and the next hidden input name before form post,so that the selected Id and Name can be binded to Sistem.Components)：

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    @foreach (var cat in @ViewBag.Categories)
    {
    
    <div class="radio-toolbar">
        @foreach (var comp in cat.Components)
        {
        
            <input type="radio" id="@comp.Id" value="@comp.Id" />
            <input hidden id="compName_@comp.Id" value="@comp.Name" />
            <label for="@comp.Id"> @comp.Name</label>
        
            
        }
    </div>
    }
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $(".radio-toolbar").each(function () {
            $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").attr("name", "Components[" + count + "].Id");
            $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").next().attr("name", "Components[" + count + "].Name");
            count++;
        })
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });
</script>
```

Controller(I use fake data to test):

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Sistem sistem = new Sistem { 
                Id=1,
                Name="sistem1",
                Components=new List<Component> 
                {
                    new Component{ Id=11, Name=11},
                    new Component{ Id=12, Name=12},
                    new Component{ Id=13, Name=13}
                }
            };
            var categories = new List<Category> 
            {
                new Category{  Components=new List<Component>
                {
                new Component{ Id=11, Name=11},
                    new Component{ Id=12, Name=12},
                    new Component{ Id=13, Name=13}
                } },
                new Category{  Components=new List<Component>
                {
                new Component{ Id=21, Name=21},
                    new Component{ Id=22, Name=22},
                    new Component{ Id=23, Name=23}
                } },
                new Category{  Components=new List<Component>
                {
                new Component{ Id=31, Name=31},
                    new Component{ Id=32, Name=32},
                    new Component{ Id=33, Name=33}
                } }
            };
            ViewBag.Categories = categories;
            return View(sistem);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Sistem sistem)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answear. The components still don t link to the sistem in my database, I have a db for Categories, one for Components and one for Sistems. Because of how I created the Models for Sistem and Component, a new database was generated: SistemComponents with only "Sistem_Id" and "Component_Id" and that s where they should assemble.

Comment: For example: In the first place a Sistem has no components. In Category 1 we have 2 Components : comp 1 and comp 2, In Category 2 we have 3 components: comp 3, comp 4 and comp 5. Now in the Create form for Sistem I want to choose one Component from each Category, let's say I choose comp 2 from category 1 and comp 4 from category 2, now the Sistem shoud have comp 2 and comp 4 in Components property and I suppose Sistem_Id 1 matches with Component_Id 2 and Sistem_Id 1 matches with Component_Id 4 too, since we have many-to-many relationship